# How to download content from a qouta exceeded LFS GitHub repo to correct the situation?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, quota

I thought I gonna try git LFS. I uploaded some of my 360 photos / videos content into an organization. I created a few repositories based on the events the photos / videos are related to. The organization and all the repos are public. I was in the belief that private free repos have 1-2 GB limit on them, didn't know that public repos have that low limits as well.

I enabled LFS to actually help GitHub (and not myself), because they have to store and manage less meta-data. So I get an email `Git LFS has been disabled on the organization Whatever because you’ve exceeded your data plan by at least 150%. Please purchase additional data packs to cover your bandwidth and storage usage: ...`

Not sure where does it makes sense for them to disable LFS. It seems like to me still enabled (see later). I want to take the files down (this is some hobby stuff I sure as hell won't pay for, I'll solve it a different way), but here comes the problem: GitHub doesn't let me clone the repo due to the exceeded quota. I thought I would download the raw files then one-by-one (which would be super annoying, but I guess learn my lesson), however I the raw view of the LFS files are still just a meta-data.

I've found a gist here: https://gist.github.com/fkraeutli/66fa741d9a8c2a6a238a01d17ed0edc5
I was hopeful, but that also didn't work: when I execute the curl command it returns `Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub`. When I execute the same POST command from ARC it returns `422 Unprocessable Entity` with the message `Your browser did something unexpected. Please try again. If the error continues, try disabling all browser extensions`.

Does anyone know a way to download such repo? I'm truly stunned. I need to access the content to correct the problem.

---

I tried https://github.com/liberapay/git-lfs-fetch.py but it errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/csaba/virtualenvs/live/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_lfs/__main__.py", line 14, in <module>
    fetch(args.git_repo, args.checkout_dir, args.verbose)
  File "/home/csaba/virtualenvs/live/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_lfs/__init__.py", line 174, in fetch
    for path, oid, size in read_lfs_metadata(checkout_dir):
  File "/home/csaba/virtualenvs/live/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_lfs/__init__.py", line 113, in read_lfs_metadata
    for path in find_lfs_files(checkout_dir):
  File "/home/csaba/virtualenvs/live/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_lfs/__init__.py", line 98, in find_lfs_files
    path, attr, value = next(i).rsplit(': ', 2)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I guess because of yet again ... quota? Tomorrow I'll debug into it. I'm in a 22 catch.

Git clone says:

```
Downloading Whatever/12634.jpg (5.1 MB)
Error downloading object: Whatever/12634.jpg (31cd545): Smudge error: Error downloading Whatever/12634.jpg (31cd545.....75b22): batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access.

Errors logged to '/home/.../.git/lfs/logs/20220613T235649.800227848.log'.
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: Whatever/12634.jpg: smudge filter lfs failed
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```